# How to check open ports using sockets

Tags: c, sockets, port

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>// for exit
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h> //for close(),read()
#include<sys/types.h>//
#include<sys/socket.h> //for socket api's
#include<netinet/in.h>//for struct sockaddr_in
#include<arpa/inet.h>// for inet_pton

#define MAX 30

int ssfd;   //listenfd
int res; //connfd
int serverlen;
struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;

void main()
{
    int i=0,res;
    int startPortRange=0;  
    int stopPortRange=65536; 

    for(i=startPortRange; i<stopPortRange; i++)  
    {  
        ssfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        if(ssfd==-1)
        {
            printf("\nSocket Creation Failed....");
        }

        serveraddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
        serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); // inet_addr converts an IPV4 from dotted decimal string
        //to e.g(127.0.0.1) to its 32-bit network byte ordered binary value.    

        serveraddr.sin_port=i;

        serverlen=sizeof(serveraddr);

        res = bind(ssfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serveraddr,serverlen);

        if(res==-1)
        {
            printf("\nPort in Use : %d",i);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nPort not in use: %d",i); 
        }

        close(ssfd);
    }
}
```

i am trying to read open ports(which are used by some programs) on computer.The program is working fine. But it doesn't gives the correct result.for eg port 3306 is used by mysql on my computer but my program outputs that it is not in use. please help me to try this out

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
serveraddr.sin_port=i;
```

you need to use

```
serveraddr.sin_port=htons(i);
```

because the port address in the inetaddr structure must have network byte order

Comment: i have added this line serveraddr.sin_port=htons(i); but it gives me the same output as previous

Answer (score 0):

You should bind to 0.0.0.0, not 127.0.0.1, otherwise you only find out what ports you can bind to 17.0.0.1, which isn't what you're trying to find out. But why you want to do this when netstat already exists is a mystery.